# How to wait for a subprocess used for I/O redirection?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, background-process, process-substitution

Consider the following snippet of Bash script:

```
exec 3> >(sleep 1; echo "$BASHPID: here")
do-something-interesting
exec 3>&-
wait $!
echo "$BASHPID: there"
```

When executed, it produces:

```
a.sh: line 4: wait: pid 1001 is not a child of this shell
1000: there
1001: here
```

How can I modify the `wait` line so that it actually waits for the termination of `1001`? In other words, I can I change the script so that the output becomes:

```
1001: here
1000: there
```

Comment: I'm surprised this actually works at all.  My understanding of exec was that the current process calling exec is totally replaced by the new process thus lines after an exec is issued would not get executed.

Comment: @mdpc: I'm not executing any command with `exec`, I'm just using it for output redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `bash` sets `$!` for that background job started with `exec 3> >(job)`, you can't wait for it or do any other things you'd be able to do with `job &` (like `fg`, `bg` or refer it by job number). `ksh93` (where `bash` got that feature from) or `zsh` don't even set `$!` there.

You could do it the standard and portable way instead:

```
{
  {
     do-something-interesting
  } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | { sleep 1; echo "$BASHPID: here"; } 4>&-
} 4>&1
echo "$BASHPID: there"
```

In `zsh` (and it's explicitly [documented](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution))

```
zmodload zsh/system
{
  do-something-interesting
} 3> >(sleep 1; echo $sysparams[pid]: here)
echo $sysparams[pid]: there
```

would also work, but not in `ksh93` or `bash`.

Comment: Many thanks! Much more complicated than I'd have expected, but surely the only solution that does not involve changing the prospective.